# How to modify the retry interval of the mysql::Pool when servers goes down?

Tags: mysql, rust

Currently, I am creating a [pool](https://docs.rs/mysql/16.0.2/mysql/struct.Pool.html) and sharing it among multiple threads, something similar to:

```
fn main() {
    let mut opts = mysql::OptsBuilder::from_opts(dsn);
    opts.stmt_cache_size(0);
    opts.read_timeout(Some(Duration::new(3, 0)));
    opts.write_timeout(Some(Duration::new(3, 0)));

    let pool = mysql::Pool::new_manual(1, 5, opts).expect("Could not connect to MySQL");

    loop {
        let wait_time = Duration::from_secs(30);
        let start = Instant::now();

        let mut funcs: Vec<fn(mysql::Pool)> = Vec::new();

        funcs.push(func1);
        funcs.push(func2);

        let mut threads = Vec::new();

        for f in funcs {
            let pool = pool.clone();
            threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
                f(pool);
            }));
        }
        for t in threads {
            let _ = t.join();
        }

        let runtime = start.elapsed();
        if let Some(remaining) = wait_time.checked_sub(runtime) {
           eprintln!("sleeping for: {}", remaining.as_secs());
           thread::sleep(remaining);
        }

        // (how to improve this) ?
        eprintln!("pool ping: {:?}", pool);
    }
}

fn func1(pool: mysql::Pool){
    let mut stmt = match pool.prepare("SELECT user, time, state, info FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command != 'Sleep' AND time >= ? ORDER BY time DESC, id LIMIT 1;") {
        Ok(stmt) => stmt,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            return;
        }
    };

    for row in stmt.execute((30,)).unwrap() {
        let (user, time, state, info) =
            mysql::from_row::<(String, i64, String, String)>(row.unwrap());
        println!("{} {} {} {}", user, time, state, info);
    }
}
```

So far all good but, when the MySQL server goes down, I see:

```
DriverError { Could not connect to address `mydb.host:3306': Connection refused (os error 61) }
```

When the MySQL server is up/reachable again, the pool establishes the connection and the queries work as expected. Therefore I would like to know if the `pool` retries indefinitely or if there is a limit of retries, besides how could the retry interval be defined/modified?

Also wondering how to handle the pool errors so that an alert could be sent for example when MySQL server is down.

Comment: Could you please include the contents of `func1` and `func2`? How are you accessing the `Pool`?

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel I updated the question with an example of what it could be `func1` or `func2`